# Update the content of a Dataset in AzureML studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

In the execution of a job in my MLOps pipeline, I want to obtain a dataset's content, modify it, and upload the new content, overwriting the old content of the file. Is there any option to do it? I have tried different forms, such as using Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_Dataframe, but it creates a new directory for the new file, and in my case, I need to replace the existing file.

```
   from azureml.core import Dataset

   dataset_test = Dataset.Tabular.from_parquet_files(path = [(ds, 'main.parquet')])
   file_dataframe = dataset_test.to_pandas_dataframe()
   file_path = 'test_dir/main.parquet'
   file_dataframe['column'] = 'new_value'
   file_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(
        dataframe=file_dataframe,
        target=(ds, file_path),
        name='main.parquet',
        description='Test upload new file'
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation below:

[azureml.data.dataset_factory.TabularDatasetFactory class - Azure Machine Learning Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-dataset-factory-tabulardatasetfactory-register-pandas-dataframe)

The **target** field in the `register_pandas_dataframe` function requires you to provide a datastore object and folder path where you need to store your parquet files, not the parquet file path.

> Required, the datastore path where the dataframe parquet data will be uploaded to. A guid folder will be generated under the target path to avoid conflict.

It is also mentioned that, to avoid conflict, a **guid** folder is created, so you cannot overwrite the existing file inside the folder.

However, you can register the dataset with the same name, using the **name** field in the `register_pandas_dataframe` function, which creates multiple versions of the data. Later, you can access the latest version, which is the updated dataset.

Example:

The code below was run three times with the same name, `Par_updates`.

```py
file_dataframe = dataset_test.to_pandas_dataframe()
file_path = 'updated'
file_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(
     dataframe=file_dataframe,
     target=(datastore, file_path),
     name="Par_updates",
     description='Test upload new file'
)
```

This creates data in three different **guid** folders with three different versions.

[image]

And in the data asset:

[image]

The third version is your latest altered version of your data, and you can access it using the code below.

```py
import mltable
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
data_asset = ml_client.data.get("Par_updates", version="3")

tbl = mltable.load(f'azureml:/{data_asset.id}')

df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df
```

[image]